# Edit Prettier (VS-Code) CSS formatting settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have a an inline CSS line with a variable that looks like this :

```
.popupSubmit {background: #{{ generic_color_10 }};color: #fff; border-color: #fff;}
```

I'm formatting it with Prettier, but the result is broken

```
.popupSubmit {
    background: #{{ generic_color_10 }
}
;
color: #fff;
border-color: #fff;

}
```

How can I edit the formatter settings to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean broken? does it not work after formatting? or do you mean its broken down like this?

Comment: No, it just looks 'ugly' and breaks line not in the right place

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using prettier to format your document, its easier to configure it according to your needs.

This behaviour is set by the setting `"prettier.printWidth: 80"` it is 80 by default and you can increase it as you like so that it wont break up the line.

You can set the value in your `settings.json` by adding `"prettier.printWidth": 120,` or in the UI (Prettier Extension Settings)

[image: PrintWidht]

You can increase it to whatever you like but beware this will apply to all languages you let prettier format with.

to disable prettier for css you can add it in th settings here:

[image]

or this in `settings.json`

```
"prettier.disableLanguages": [
    "css"
]
```

As mentioned in comments, OP doesn't want validation of his CSS to occur

to do that set `"css.validate": false` in `settings.json`

[image: CSS Validation]

Comment: Thanks. But now it won't format and gives me a syntax error. 

["ERROR" - 12:54:05 PM] (postcss) CssSyntaxError Unexpected } (2:41)
  1 | /** global.css **/
> 2 | body {background:#{{ generic_color_1 }};}

Can I disable it?

Comment: This will disable CSS formatting at all, what i'm trying to do is disable CSS syntax check. Possible?

Comment: The thing is Prettier is just a formatter and the linting, ie problem/error checking is done by VSCode itself for CSS. For vscode to stop showing errors you need to tell VSCode and not Prettier to not show errors. I will add the settings to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts but it's not working. I can't see why